Kubuntu Monitor Flickering Notebook HP
I installed Kubuntu 24.04 on my HP notebook, but I have monitor flickering in alternating phases. I have the following graphics:
Intel Corporation HD Graphics 620 (rev 02) graphics card (prog-if 00 [VGA controller]

How can I solve the problem?

Please note that this is a English only site.

Add yourself here if it applies to you https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/2064189
